# Is it possible to list private rooms on Unity multiplayer game

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, multiplayer

I am developing multiplayer game on Unity personal edition and I want to let user create public and private rooms. But I am not sure how to show private rooms to the users. Is it possible to list them on room listing screens?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: I haven't started on multiplayer part but i heard that unity doesnt allow private room listing. They let you create private room but you can't list them to show players. However this was unoffical resource and not sure about it. So i would be appreciate if anyone knows something about this.